# Webview within dialog sometimes not shows image

Tags: android, dialog, webview, progress-bar

I have a simple application with one button, when the button is pressed a dialog opens with a progress bar.
When the url is loaded it shows an image in a webview.
The funny thing is, if you press it a 100 times, it doesn't open sometimes.
Tested it on a real device on android 2.3.3 and emulator 4.0.3.

Does someone know why?

HelloWebViewActivity.java

```
public class HelloWebViewActivity extends Activity {

ProgressBar progressBar;
WebView a;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
  setContentView(R.layout.main );

  TextView buttona = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button);
  buttona.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HelloWebViewActivity.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        a = (WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.webview); 
        a.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);      
        a.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        a.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            if(progress == 100) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
    });
      a.loadUrl("http://www.deshow.net/d/file/car/2010-10/seat-electric-car-879-2.jpg");
      dialog.setCancelable(true);
      dialog.show();
      }
  }); 

}
}
```

webview.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


 <ProgressBar 
     android:id="@+id/progressbar"
     style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="20dp"
     android:max="100"
     android:visibility="gone" />

 <WebView
     android:id="@+id/webview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not solve it but made a work around.
I made the webview in a new activity with a onResume thing that retrieves the url of the image.
This way the image is loaded in a activity instead of a dialog, what looks less fancy but it always loads with a progress wheel.